# append to file android

Tags: java, android

hey there, i need to append to my file but it is not working, it keeps overwriting the file,  can anyone please tell me what is wrong:

```
  public void generateNoteOnSD(String sBody){

        try
        {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AdidasParticipants");

            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();

            }

            File gpxfile = new File(root, "participants.txt");

            BufferedWriter bW;

            bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile));
            bW.write(sBody);
            bW.newLine();
            bW.flush();
            bW.close();
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Tus datos han sido guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
          //   importError = e.getMessage();
            // iError();
        }
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not working... how? Not writing? Error message? What?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can fix it by changing the line where you assign the `BufferedWriter`:

```
bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile, true));
```

When you open a file using the `FileWriter` constructor that only takes in a `File`, it will overwrite what was previously in the file.  Supplying the second parameter as `true` tells the `FileWriter` that you want to append to the end of it.