# Adding new lines of text in a text file

Tags: java

My app records sounds. Once the sound is recorded, user is asked to input a new file name. Now what I'm trying to do next is to add all file names in a text file so that I can read it later as an array to make a listview.

This is the code:

```
//this is in onCreate
File recordedFiles = new File(externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/recorded files.txt");
if(!recordedFiles.exists())
    {
            try {
                recordedFiles.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
//this executes everytime text is entered and the button is clicked
try {
            String content = input.getText().toString();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(recordedFiles.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(">" + content + ".mp3");
            bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now the problem is that everytime I record a new file, the previous line is overwritten. So if I record two files 'text1' and 'text2', after I've recorded text1, the txt file will show text1, but after I recorded the text2, the text2 will overwrite the text1 instead of inserting a new line.

I tried adding:

```
bw.NewLine()
```

before

```
bw.write(">" + content + ".mp3");
```

but it doesn't work.

If I record three sounds and name them sound1, sound2 and sound3, I want this to be the result:

```
>sound1
>sound2
>sound3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5987040/2500326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FileWriter` constructor with `boolean append` argument

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(recordedFiles.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
//                                                              ^^^^
```

this will let file append text at the end instead overwriting previous content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by  adding `line.separator` [Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

```
 bw.write(">" + content + ".mp3");
 bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter` takes a boolean if it should overwrite. So use `true` if you would like to to append to the file instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(recordedFiles.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Instead of

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(recordedFiles.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```