# Android: Append to file instead of ovewriting

Tags: java, android, text

I am trying to append to a text file but for some reason it keeps overwriting it, here's my code:

```
File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "notifications.txt");
                try {
                if(!logFile.exists()) {
                     logFile.createNewFile();
                }

                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); // build the string
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile)); //Buffered reader used to read the file
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // if not empty continue
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
                output.write(text + "\n");
                output.close();
                alertDialog.show();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

use

```
new FileWriter(logFile, true)
```

Where the second parameter tells it to append, not overwrite.

Found in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987012/append-to-file-android?rq=1) In the related questions on the right.

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the other constructor of `FileWriter` that specifies whether the data is overwritten or appended. Use `FileWriter(logFile, true)` instead of what you have now :)